# How to improve my factorial function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, factorial

I am new to python and I am required to create a factorial function. I have created a function that gives the factorial of a number but I want some help from stackflow community.

Here is my code

```
a = 5
b = 1
for i in range(1,a+1):
    b = b * i
    print b
```

And this is my output:

[image]

I am getting 120 (factorial value) but I am also getting other values like 1, 2, 6. How can I only print factorial value and not other values.

Comment: Just a note that you can use `b *= i` instead of `b = b * i`

Comment: a function begins with a `def` statement. What you have code that computes the factorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `Math` library in the Python, Try this following code

```
import math
math.factorial(5)
```

> Answer : 120

Or, 
In your Code, you are trying to print the 'b' inside the loop, So your getting prints in every loop time, just put the `print b` in the out side of the loop

```
a = 5
b = 1
for i in range(1,a+1):
    b = b * i
print b
```

Comment: Well I don;t get it. I mean why is the print command inside the loop causing repetition of variable "b" ? It would be great if you could explain the difference between putting the print inside loop and outside loop

Comment: when you are using `print b` inside the loop, then it execute every time of the loop so you will get the print every time. But you want the print in the last time only(The final value only) so just put the `print b` in the outside of the loop, then that command will be executed after the Loop, so you can get the final value of the loop.

Comment: if is it good for your knowledge, then accept my answer, Thank you

Comment: I actually used your code, Thanks a lot. But I wanted to know the reason behind the code  and not just copy it blindly.

Comment: `Math` is a python library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html). So the `factorial()` is a function of the library

Answer (score 0):

Unindent the `print` statement so that it is only executed after the loop instead of within it, for every step.

```
a = 5
b = 1
for i in range(1,a+1):
    b = b * i
print b
```

Comment: Adding a proper `return` statement to the function would be great.

Comment: @9000 - All that would do is cause an error, because there's no function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you a different approach:

```
def fact(n):
    return reduce(lambda accum, element: accum * element, range(1, n+1), 1)

print fact(5)  # prints 120
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write a function then you'll want something more like this:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

This calculates the factorial recursively. If you want an iterative function then the following will do it:

```
def factorial(n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        res *= i
    return res
```

Otherwise, you could just import the math library and use math.factorial(n) if you don't need to create the function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Factorials are best calculated with a generator function. To retrieve the last item you can use [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

```
def factorial(n):
    ct = 1
    factor = 1
    while ct <= n:
        yield factor
        ct = ct+1
        factor = factor * ct
from collections import deque
x = deque(factorial(10), maxlen=1).pop()
x
3628800
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the factorial using reduce from the functools module.

```
from functools import reduce
def fact(n):
    print(reduce(lambda n, m: n*m, list(range(1, n+1))))
fact(5) # Output: 120
```